# layout above and below of listview but above layout is getting hide

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one problem. I have below a layout XML where I have a ListView between two 
layouts. My problem is that when I run the application, the above layout i.e. topButtonsBar is getting hide. Please help me to solve my issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topButtonsBar"
        android:background="#4777"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sectionFilter"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/filter"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/app_icon"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:transcriptMode="disabled"
        android:scrollingCache="true" 

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/navBar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#4777"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/firehose"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/article"

            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/weather"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/weather"

            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/traffic"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/traffic"

            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/livestream"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/video"

            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/moreSections"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/categories"

            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: make parent layout orientation as vertical..

Comment: try using relative layout properties i.e layout_above and layout below in your list view if its overlapping with something.This way it will be between those layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Paste below layout, it will working fine, just replace your Images name as I have used ic_launcher.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topButtonsBar"
        android:background="#4777"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sectionFilter"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/filter"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageButton
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:transcriptMode="disabled"
        android:scrollingCache="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topButtonsBar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/navBar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#4777"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/firehose"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"

            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/weather"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"

            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/traffic"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"

            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/livestream"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/moreSections"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:padding="6dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topButtonsBar"
    android:background="#4777"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sectionFilter"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/filter"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageButton
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" 
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:transcriptMode="disabled"
    android:scrollingCache="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/topButtonsBar"
    android:layout_above="@+id/navBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/navBar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#4777"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/firehose"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/article"

        android:padding="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/weather"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/weather"

        android:padding="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/traffic"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/traffic"

        android:padding="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/livestream"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/video"

        android:padding="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/moreSections"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/categories"

        android:padding="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hi ravi,i have tried yor trick, but problem is above and below layouts becomes solid.i want those two transperent so that we can see the scrollong of list view items

Comment: remove above and below from listview, this might help you

Comment: my above layout becomes solid instead of transperent so that is not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The parent layout is a RelativeLayout, you should add **layout_below** to your ListView just like this

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topButtonsBar"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:scrollingCache="true"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:transcriptMode="disabled" />
```

This will make your ListView below the first layout.

Comment: but my above layout becomes solid, instead i want that layout transperent opeque